# OnItemClickListener not working properly in recyclerView after adding setTextColor?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that contain a recyclerview that shows time slots in a cardviews, as shown below

[image]

**What I want:** if user clicks a cardview the word Available changes to Full and the text color turns to red, as shown below when clicking 7:30 slot

[image]

**The problem:** after adding setTextColor() to textview in onbindViewHolder,
the changes (text to “Full” , color to red) applies to the clicked card, but when I scroll  recyclerview I find another card change text color to red without changing of the text to “Full” in a random position  !!

[image]

**My adapter code:**
    class TimeSlotAdapter(private val timeSlotsList: ArrayList): RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
private var mListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

interface OnItemClickListener {
          fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}

fun setOnItemClickListener (listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    mListener = listener
}

class TimeSlotViewHolder(card: View, listener: OnItemClickListener?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(card){

    var mCardTime: TextView = card.findViewById(R.id.timeTV)
    var mAvailability: TextView = card.findViewById(R.id.availabilityTV)

    init {

        card.setOnClickListener {
            if (listener != null) {
                val position = adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    listener.onItemClick(position)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TimeSlotViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.time_slot, parent, false)
    return TimeSlotViewHolder(v, mListener)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = timeSlotsList.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TimeSlotViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = timeSlotsList[position]

    holder.mCardTime.text = currentItem.cardTime
    holder.mAvailability.text = currentItem.availability

    if (currentItem.isSelected) {

    // the problem when I add the below
        holder.mAvailability.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    }
}
```

**activity fragment code:**
    class ReserveTimeFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var timeSlotsList: ArrayList<TimeSlot>? = null

private var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var mAdapter: TimeSlotAdapter? = null
private var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reserve_time, container, false)

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewLO)

    createTimeSlotsList()
    buildRecyclerView()

    return view
}

fun buildRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    mAdapter = TimeSlotAdapter(timeSlotsList!!)

    mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    mRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdapter

    mAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener(object : TimeSlotAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
            selectedItem(position, "Full", false)
        }
    })
}

fun selectedItem(position: Int, text: String, selected: Boolean) {
    timeSlotsList!![position].changeAvailability(text)
    timeSlotsList!![position].selecteditem(selected)
    mAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private fun createTimeSlotsList() {
    timeSlotsList = ArrayList()
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("07:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("08:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("08:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("09:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("09:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("10:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("10:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("11:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("11:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("12:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("12:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("13:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("13:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("14:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("14:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("15:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("15:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("16:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("16:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("17:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("17:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("18:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("18:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("19:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("19:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("20:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("20:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("21:00", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("21:30", "Available", false))
    timeSlotsList!!.add(TimeSlot("22:00", "Available", false))

}
```

}

**How to fix this problem, please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    if (currentItem.isSelected) {

    // the problem when I add the below
        holder.mAvailability.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    }
```

I haven't tested this code but with my experience, it should be:

```java
    if (currentItem.isSelected) {
        holder.mAvailability.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    } else {
        holder.mAvailability.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ken I implemented the else statement, and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I believe you simply have recycling-related issues.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TimeSlotViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = timeSlotsList[position]

    holder.mCardTime.text = currentItem.cardTime
    holder.mAvailability.text = currentItem.availability

    if (currentItem.isSelected) {

    // the problem when I add the below
        holder.mAvailability.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    }
}
```

To put it simply, consider here a recycler view: you check if it's selected, then set its text color to RED. What if not?

You should consider all cases in `onBindViewHolder`, which would mean to implement an `else` statement to handle a recycler view:

```
holder.mAvailability.setTextColor(if (currentItem.isSelected) Color.RED else Color.GREEN)
```

Comment: Thanks, shkschneider everything seems to work fine after implementing else statement